# Algorithm RGB to Gray Lagging

Tags: java, opencv, optimization, colors, lag

Trying to implements the conversion method that converts a picture from RGB to Gray.
When i use my method and display the rendering in an ImageView , it's lags so much and when i use the cvtColor, function from the library OpenCV it works like a charm.
Can anyone explain me where is the problem ?
here's my method:

```
public void RGBToGray(Mat m){
    for(int i = 0; i < m.rows(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m.cols(); j++){
            double[] pix = m.get(i, j);
            pix[0] = pix[1] = pix[2] = (0.21)*pix[0]+(0.72)*pix[1]+(0.07)*pix[2];
            m.put(i, j, pix);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You lack the parallelization and vectorization of the `cvtColor` implementation in OpenCV. On top of that, you have two function calls per iteration -- IIRC this will involve JNI and as such would have some associated overhead (becoming much more pronounced if instead of one call per image you have two for every pixel.

Comment: Your calls to `m.get` and `m.put` will consume a lot of time. Note that the ITU (International Telecommnications Union) defines the equation as `Grey = 0.299Red + 0.587Green + 0.114Blue`, which in my experience works great.

Comment: Really, considering you're using `Mat`, there's little reason for this for loop. OpenCV provides method to split `Mat` into single channels, [optimized operations to multiply whole `Mat` by a scalar](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Core.html#add(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)), as well as to add them together, and merge channels back into a multi-channel `Mat`.

Comment: Okay, so avoiding m.get and m.put would fix it , but how am i gonna implements the algorithm without those functions ? , i mean dividing a mat into 2 matrices , applying a scale and then merge them , those operations  how do they work ? isn't it by a for loop to modify every pixel ?

Comment: Something like [`split`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.11/org/opencv/core/Core.html#split(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20java.util.List)), 3x [`scaleAdd`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.11/org/opencv/core/Core.html#scaleAdd(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20double,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)) to a single channel "gray" `Mat`. If you need the result to be 3 channels, then any of `merge` (insert the same "gray" `Mat` 3 times into the input `List`), `mixChannels` or `cvtColor` would do the job. | Other option is to use `get` to fetch an array of all the pixels at once and do your loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reponses (y) , i did that , and it worked all fine (y),
1)- I would like now to have an explanation why the put and the get methods take so much time.
2)- i would like to implements the Median filter, so i need to access the pixels one by one, any way to avoid put/get methods for that purpose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution for those who will see the post according to Dan Masek comment:

```
public static void RGBToGray2(Mat m){
    ArrayList<Mat> sousMatrices = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    Core.split(m, sousMatrices);
    Mat result = new Mat();
    Core.addWeighted(sousMatrices.get(0), 0.21, sousMatrices.get(1), 0.72, 0, result);
    Core.addWeighted(sousMatrices.get(2), 0.07, result, 1 ,0 , result);
    sousMatrices.set(0,result);
    sousMatrices.set(1,result);
    sousMatrices.set(2,result);
    Core.merge(sousMatrices, m);
}
```